# Windows 8 store app. ListView. Touch item scroll and Pointer* events

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have listView with items:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="_listView" SelectionMode="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" IsTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>


public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
        {
            Border _border = new Border();
            _border.Width = 400;
            _border.Height = 300;
            _border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255));
            _border.PointerPressed += _border_PointerPressed;
            _border.PointerReleased += _border_PointerReleased;
            _border.PointerExited += _border_PointerExited;
            _border.PointerEntered += _border_PointerEntered;
            //_border.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            _listView.Items.Add(_border);
        }
    }

    void _border_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }

    void _border_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255));
    }

    void _border_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 255));
    }

    void _border_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = sender as Border;
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0));
    }
```

When i try use touch in items - PointerExited, PointerReleased, PointerMoved - not fired. If i uncomment _border.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All - events fired, but scroll not work :( . Tell me please, if it's pussibele, how to achieve trigger these events and scrolling ? Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Can you use a button?

Comment: I have a UserControl with Image. I want show Border (whit custom BorderBrush and BorderThickness), when pointer is located in control. And hide, when pointer exited. Thank you. Sorry for my English. :(

Comment: Ah, ok well this is handled for you with buttons already. You should take a look at VisualState to learn more

Comment: try enabling  SelectionMode?

Comment: Thank you. With buttons it's work. I wonder why this is happening with Border? I do not know how to search it. Please tell me where I can read about how it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ManipulationModes.All|ManipulationModes.System`.

Comment: WinRT information: Invalid ManipulationModes combination.

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. :(

Comment: Try only the options you use